Inchoative aspect and movement verbs
I'm relatively new to the topic of grammaticalization and I'm investigating the grammaticalization of motion verbs, e.g. the movement verb gaan ('to go') can have an inchoative function in Dutch (Ze gaat huilen. = 'She starts to cry'). I'm now wondering how this function of gaan did emerge. There is also a periphrastic structure in Dutch in which gaan still has a spatial meaning: Ze gaat slapen. = 'She goes to sleep'). Could one now assume that the inchoative function emerged from the spatial one, or did the periphrastic structure emerge directly from the motion verb gaan? How might this semantic change have occurred? Are there any experiences from other languages?
I know it's a very specific question, but maybe someone can help me or point to existing research.
Regards

Typically you would approach this sort of problem by trying to find contexts for reanalysis. Since grammaticalization starts with more lexical meanings, you start with a purely spatial meaning: ze gaat naar bed 'she is going to bed'. Once verbal goals are permitted, i.e. ze gaat (naar bed om te) slapen 'she is going (to bed) to sleep', we have a context in which gaan can be interpreted either spatially or inchoatively. This allows for reanalysis as an inchoative, which enables the extension to ze gaat huilen 'she is going to cry', in which no motion is implied.
In the abstract, therefore, you need an ambiguous context so that reanalysis can apply, yielding a new meaning that can be extended to new contexts.
